# Sum Log values from table using second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge table where a new row could be an "adjustment" to a previous row.

TableA:

```
Id   | RefId |   TransId    |Score 
----------------------------------
101  |  null |    3001      |  10
102  |  null |    3002      |  15
103  |  null |    3003      |  15
104  |  101  |              |  -5
105  |  null |    3004      |   5
106  |  105  |              | -10 
107  |  null |    3005      |  15
```

TableB:

```
TransId | Person 
----------------
3001  |  Harry
3002  |  Draco
3003  |  Sarah 
3004  |  Ron 
3005  |  Harry
```

In the table above, Harry was given 10 points in TableA.Id=101, deducted 5 of those points in TableA.Id=104, and then given another 15 points in TableA.Id=107.

What I want to do here, is return all the rows where Harry is the person connected to the score. The problem is that there is no name attached to a row where points are deducted, only to the rows where scores are given (through TableB). However, scores are always deducted from a previously given score, where the original transaction's Id is referred to in the tables as "RefId".

```
SELECT 
SUM TableA.Score 
FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Trans=TableB.TransId
WHERE 1
AND TableB.Person='Harry'
GROUP BY TableA.Score
```

That only gives me the points given to Harry, not the deducted ones. I would like to get the total scored returned, which would be 20 for Harry. (10-5+15=20)

How do I get MySQL to include the negative scores as well? I feel like it should be possible using the TableA.RefId. Something like "if there is a RefId, get the score from this row, but look at the corresponding TableA.Id for the rest of the data".

Comment: Your data structure is a tree and MySQL provides basically no support to traversing trees or graphs.  You will probably need to create a stored procedure to do this or to change the layout of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 select sum(sum1 + sums) as sum_all from (
      SELECT  t1.id,T1.Score sum1, coalesce(T2.score,0) sums
      FROM Table1 t1
      inner JOIN Table2 ON T1.TransId=Table2.TransId
      left JOIN Table1 t2 ON  t2.RefId = t1.id 
       WHERE  Table2.Person='Harry'
      )c
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7244ea/2)

OUTput:

```
 SUM_ALL
 20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select sum(total) AS total
From tableb
Join
(
  Select t1.transid, sum(score) AS total
  From tablea t1
  Join tablea t2 on t1.id = t2.refid
  group by t1.transid
) x on x.transid = tableb.transid
Where TableB.Person='Harry'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that adjustments don't modify adjustments, you can do this without aggregating all the data:

```
select sum(a.score + coalesce(aref.score, 0)) as HarryScore
from tableA a left outer join
     tableA aref
     on a.refId = aref.id left outer join
     tableB b
     on a.TransId = b.Transid left outer join
     tableB bref
     on aref.TransId = bref.TransId
where b.Person = 'Harry' or bref.Person = 'Harry';
```